# Using rake db:migrate straight, vanilla SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

What gotchas would be involved by using `rake db:migrate` to load vanilla SQL?

The business requirements that I am working with don't allow me to use the default Rails' migrations. But I still need to track changes, easily alter the database DDL, and the other things that Rails' migrations give you.

So a migration file would look like:

```
class AddDateToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE `posts` ADD COLUMN date DATETIME NULL")
  end

  def self.down
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE `posts` DROP COLUMN date")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17):

That's perfectly acceptable and there are no gotchas, as long as you feel confident that your up and down functions mirror each other. I would suggest doing the following for readability:

```
class AddDateToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE `posts` ADD COLUMN date DATETIME NULL"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "ALTER TABLE `posts` DROP COLUMN date"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rails migration methods in a non-rails project by using the [`standalone-migrations` gem](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations).

After installing the gem you add the following lines to your `Rakefile` to enable `rake db:*` tasks:

```
require 'standalone_migrations'
StandaloneMigrations::Tasks.load_tasks
```

After that you simply setup your migrations as you would normally do:

```
class AddDateToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_columm :posts, :date, :datetime, default: nil
  end

  def self.down
    remove_columm :posts, :date
  end
end
```